# Sort Alphanumeric column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I am not an SQL expert. I've been searching over google on how to achieve below.
I need to sort my records based on ID. (prefix first and then their numerical values)

```
Table: CUSTOMER_TRANS

| ID       | Name   | Date       |
|==========|========|============|
|CP-091435 | Ola    | 01-01-2010 |
|WM-183258 | Tor    | 09-09-2001 |
|CP-109056 | Jess   | 03-03-2003 |


SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TRANS ORDER BY substr(ID, 4) desc;
```

I need to sort first the 2 prefix e.g ES and then the numerical values.
However, my SQL above returns only the numerical highest WM-183258.
The expected result is to returns first the "CP" prefix and the highest in numerical value e.g. below.  Hope someone can give me somelight.

**Expected Result:**

```
| ID       | Name   |
|==========|========|
|CP-109056 | Ola    | 
|CP-091435 | Jess   | 
|WM-183258 | Tor    |
```

Comment: So you need it sorted by the prefix ascending and number descending, correct?

Comment: If I do that the result is WM-183258 becomes at the top. The ID expected at the top is the CP-109056 (as shown on the 2nd table). @Phil

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't read your question correctly. I've updated my comment for clarity

Comment: Yes correct. I need to sort the prefix first asc and then the numerical values to desc. @Phil

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you very much @Phil. You saved my day.. thank you. Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My PL/SQL is quite rusty but you should be able to use something like

```
... ORDER BY substr(ID, 1, 2) ASC, substr(ID, 4) DESC
```

**or even better as pointed out by [mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)**

```
... ORDER BY substr(ID, 1, 2) ASC, ID DESC
```

That is, sort by the first two characters ascending, then by the rest descending.

---

That's probably quite sub-optimal from a performance perspective. I would consider breaking up that `ID` into it's parts, eg

```
ID_PREFIX CHAR(2),
ID_SUFFIX CHAR(6) -- or a numeric type, whatever is appropriate
```

and create your primary key on both. That makes it easy to group and sort and for display, you can just use

```
SELECT ID_PREFIX || '-' || ID_SUFFIX AS ID...
```

Comment: Note that SUBSTR treats the first character as position 1, not 0.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp gah stoopid Oracle. Thanks, though apparently zero is treated the same as `1`

Comment: That's right; SUBSTR starts counting from the first character, and emits it as long as the character is >= the start position requested - so zero works just as well (just runs the risk of being confusing for someone coming from other backgrounds).

Comment: Note that - after ordering by the alphabetic fragment - ordering by the numeric part becomes equivalent to ordering by the entire string. That is, the second ordering expression can be `ID` itself. This will save one function call per row.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [this one](http://rextester.com/ODCRZ75548) :

```
with CUSTOMER_TRANS(Id,Name) as
(
 select 'CP-091435','Ola' from dual union all    
 select 'WM-183258','Tor' from dual union all
 select 'CP-109056','Jess' from dual   
)
select *
  from CUSTOMER_TRANS
 order by substr(ID, 1, 2), substr(ID,4,length(ID)) desc;

| ID       | Name   |
|==========|========|
|CP-109056 | Jess   | 
|CP-091435 | Ola    | 
|WM-183258 | Tor    |
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to make the code understandable the next person is to use virtual columns

```
Alter table CUSTOMER_TRANS add(prefix generated always as (substr(longid,1,2)) virtual,
                     suffix generated always as (substr(longid,4)) virtual);
```

Then you can just "Order by prefix, suffix desc